# How to write sequence of machine code in radare2?

Tags: radare2, patching

I know how to write an opcode and how to increment and decrement machine code using plus and minus keys. However, how do I write a sequence of machine code at an offset?

E.g. if I want to write five 0x90, how would I do that?

Comment: That didn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > w? 
>   wx[?][fs] 9090       write two intel nops (from wxfile or wxseek)

First seek to the address you want to write, then write:

```
> s 0x000009d5
> wx 34313335
```

You can also use:

```
> w \x34\x31\x33\x35
```

This will write '4135' at the address pointed by `s` command

Radare2 also give you the option to point to the address that you want to write on:

```
> w \x34\x31\x33\x35 @0x000007b0
```

Write "4135" at 0x000007b0

Use the one you feel more comfortable.